# when keyboard is used for a input within a ion-footer, all layouts are shifted on top in Ionic 3

Tags: android-layout, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-softkeyboard

I’d doing a chat app in IONIC 3.

I put a ion-footer with a ion-textarea to write message. If I click in it, keyboard is showed (as expected), but when I go back to the previous view, all layout is shifted to the top (so navigator bar is hidden) as the keyboard would fill the layout space.

The device that I’m using is Nexus 5x and SO is 8.0.0.

I tried to change in the AndroidManifest the windowSoftInputMode value but with no success, in fact:

1. If I put “adjustPan” I solve the problem above, but when keyboard is
   showed, ion-textarea is covered by keyboard
2. If I put “adjustResize” I can
       see ion-textarea but I have the problem above :-(

I try to write it on the [Ionic Forum,](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/if-use-keyboard-in-a-textinput-at-the-ion-footer-the-previous-view-loose-navigator/110177) but nobody replied to me.

This is the wished layout

[image]

But when I move in the detail chat page and use keyboard

[image]

and choose to came back to the list page, Navigator bar is not visible 'cos layout is shifted

[image]

Did anybody have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange this framework...
I recreated the app and reimported all needed plugins and all works now.
I didn't change any code...